# Rewrite PHP query string?

Tags: .htaccess

I've searched for other solutions to rewriting a URL using the .htaccess file at the root of my server, but the language is pretty confusing to me, and I can't seem to get it to work. How would I go about changing:

```
http://domain.com/share.php?media=059ogbuq70
```

to:

```
http://domain.com/059ogbuq70
```

I found code similar to this, and tried it, but it didn't seem to work:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^media=([0-9]+)$
RewriteRule ^$ share.php?media=$1 [QSA,L]
```

My PHP:

```
<?php
$media_id = $_GET['media'];
$url = file_get_contents("https://api.wistia.com/v1/medias/" . $media_id . ".json?api_password=my_key");
$json = json_decode($url, true);
$name = $json[name];
$origimg = $json['thumbnail'][url];
list($image, $size) = explode('?', $origimg);
$video = $json['assets'][5][url];
?>
```

I then `echo` the variables where I need them on my page.

Thank you!

Comment: I'm confused. You rewrite the URL to include a query string, but only if the query string exists. Do you want to redirect from the first to the second URL?

Comment: Basically I want the pretty url to only show to user, while the real url is what is used by the server/php

Comment: Do you also want to redirect "ugly" URLs to the corresponding "pretty" ones?

Comment: No, I just need `domain.com/[some-string]` to act like `domain.com/share.php?media=[some-string]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To internally rewrite "pretty" URLs so that query strings are passed to PHP, I recommend the following `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ share.php?media=$1 [L]
```

The regex matches:
One or more characters that are not a backslash, optionally followed by a backslash.

Everything but the optional trailing slash are captured in `$1` and rewritten as the "media" query string variable.

For example:

> `http://domain.com/059ogbuq70/`
>   rewrites internally to
>   `http://domain.com/share.php?media=059ogbuq70`

Which means that:

> `$_GET['media']` = 059ogbuq70

---

You might find this [mod_rewrite cheat sheet](http://www.cheatography.com/davechild/cheat-sheets/mod-rewrite/) helpful for building your regex.
Also, you can [test your rewrites](http://htaccess.mwl.be/) here.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but this one is not rewriting the URL, and it's is interfering with my PHP (Getting variable from URI param `media=`).

Comment: Perhaps there is something else going on or I'm not understanding what you're aiming for. The rewrite is internal, so you won't see the URL change in the browser (redirect). It seems to be working [here](http://htaccess.mwl.be/). It might help to edit your PHP code into your question.

Comment: I stand corrected, inputting a URL: `domain.com/[some-string]` does seem to be working just fine, but I'm having an issue with calling the `$media_id` variable on line 3 of my PHP. It was working just fine before the URL rewrite, and it works if I delete `.htaccess`

Comment: What is the value of `$media_id` with and without the `.htaccess` file?

Comment: With `.htaccess`, it was returned as `failed`. So it was trying to read `failed.json` from the Wistia API. Without, it reads correctly as `059ogbuq70`.

Comment: Given your code, I don't see any way the `$_GET` variable would be set to "failed". "Failed" is one of the [status values Wistia returns](http://wistia.com/doc/data-api#media_status). Are you sure that's the value of `$media_id`? This is quickly deviating from the original question. Maybe it's best to ask a new question?

Comment: Thanks showdev. I'll do that. But thanks for the help in successfully rewriting the url!

Answer (score 1):

You need `two` rules for what you are trying to do. You can place this in the file called `.htaccess`

```
RewriteEngine on

#redirect all old URLs to the new rewritten URL
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /+share\.php\?media=([^&\ ]+)
RewriteRule ^ /%1? [R=302,L]

#rewrite folder path internally to share.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ share.php?media=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but this one redirects to: `http://vipheo.com/fs6e/vipheo/public/83s371n1yi%20HTTP/1.0` and gives me a 404. Any help?

Comment: @user1661677 yes sorry I corrected the the rule. Small error. Now the whole rule is complete. If you don't have a rule such as this, users will still be able to use the `http://example.com/share.php?media=13e43` style URL.