# rewrite query string with .htaccess without altering link structure

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, query-string, friendly-url

I would like to remove the query string from the URL and rewrite it without the query string without having to re-code the link structure.

I have added this:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} .
RewriteRule ^$ /? [R,L]
```

to the end of my existing .htaccss code (so that it is the last thing that is done, since there are other re-write rules before this) but the query string is not removed. What am I doing wrong?

This is the content of my current .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^userfiles/ - [L]
RewriteRule ^userdata/ - [L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php\?p=(?!admin)(?!superadmin)((?![^&]*?edit)[^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php\?p=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1? [R=301,L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ index.php?p=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Also I have a general question about how that affects the availability of query strings as variables... in other words if I re-write the URL to NOT show the query strings, is that query string still available if in PHP I write $_GET['q'] or will it then be not set anymore?
Thanks

Comment: Thank you for showing your efforts in your question. Could you please do show your complete htaccess file in your question, we may need NOT to write an additional rules we could remove the query string within your existing rules itself, so please do post it and we will get better picture of your question, thank you.

Comment: Sure @RavinderSingh13 - i'll add it to my question since I can't add code in these comments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your shown samples, could you please try following once. Please make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URLs. While redirecting remove query string because your other rule is NOT actually redirecting, if this is what you want to have then this change may help you here.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^userfiles/ - [L]

RewriteRule ^userdata/ - [L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php\?p=(?!admin)(?!superadmin)((?![^&]*?edit)[^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php\?p=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ index.php?p=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: That worked @RavinderSingh13 - thank you!

Could you tell me what removing QSA does?

Comment: @marcnyc, Your welcome(`QSA` is responsible to tell url that I am adding query string also while redirection in your tried rules here) and happy learning and sharing on this great forum, have a nice day :)

Comment: And also could you answer the last question of my post?

Comment: @marcnyc, Sorry I am not an expert of php but I know one thing you can make a url user friendly(without actual url on browser) and from backend you can have query string rewrite and there may be someway to pass it to php I am pretty sure but I am sorry I am not aware of it, but I am pretty sure if rewrite is available then it could be gettable by php too, cheers.

Comment: @marcnyc, I just did a quick SO search and got this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/34406119/5866580 please check this once if this helps you? Looks like a perfect example to me what you are asking here.